# Why is the Unity launcher pixelated after suspend on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, launcher, suspend, nouveau

Having a lot of issues with suspend on Ubuntu 13.04.

Can't wake up after suspending when using Nouveau driver (nVidia quadro fx370).
When using every single proprietary driver on the list, the Unity launcher looks pixelated (see picture).

[image: unity picture]

Comment: hi ,where is the picture ?

Comment: After one month of installing/uninstalling kernels & nvidia drivers the problem persists. This is happening only on ubuntu 13.04.Every previous distribution works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by installing a kernel below 3.5.0* I use linux-3.3.8-1 and my problem has gone with nouveau drivers.